# hiding uitoolbar leaves gap at the top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have three viewcontrollers all in a navigation stack. The first view controller does not utilize the uitoolbar, the second one does and the third one does not.

The problem is, when I go from the second UIViewController to the third UITableViewController, if I hide the toolbar, there is a white gap at the top of the screen.

Here's a picture:

[image: gap at top]

I currently have `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];`
in the viewWillDisappear of the second view controller, but I've also put it in the third view controller's viewWillAppear method. Both cause the gap to appear.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When are you hiding the toolbar?  Before or after the push, and in which method?

Comment: I updated the question to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend using `setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO` to have the new UIViewController appear without the toolbar. I think your method will show it initially and then it disappears, right? If you use the `animated:NO` (or else use the method signature without `animated:`), the new UIViewController should "push" off the UIToolbar for the 2nd UIViewController when the 3rd UIViewController is pushed onto the screen.

Secondly, you probably need to have a look at your shocks and struts for your UIViewController's view in Interface Builder. That is almost certainly what's causing this gap. You probably want to have a fixed top and bottom margin and a flexible height.

Comment: the struts for the table view are connected to the top, bottom, left, and right of the screen.

Comment: Do you have a flexible height? That is, is the up-and-down double pointed arrow clicked or not?

Comment: Yes. This is a UITableViewController and it won't let me change that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question, but I'm not going to accept it because it is hacky.

I was able to fix it by adding this line of code at the beginning of viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 493)];
```

Basically, I set the tableview frame's height to be 13 pixels bigger than the size of a full screen (which is 320 x 480).

Comment: While this may work in the short-term, please trust me that you're better off figuring out how to do it elegantly, because you may need the same function for a different app in landscape, for an iPad, etc.